# Lua pattern is not working properly when 0 is missing in the last row

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

below is my pattern which is working fine against the given string.

```
local tempRec = [[

ABC01-USD-0322-A Total DUE amount : 2312.08  USD
Value Date : 31 MAY       2011
   Details:ABCDE - BCD: / ABC01 0212 23.79 / ARM01 0311 870.79
   Details:FGHIJ - BCD: / ABC01 0323 1.88
   Details:KLMNO - BCD: / ABC01 0314 1,035.99
   Details:PQRST - BCD: / ABC01 0315 677.61
   Details:UVWXY - BCD: / ABC01 0316 362.75
   Details:ZABCD - BCD: / ABC01 0317   0.28

   ]]

paytternToMatch = "(%w%w%w[%w%d][%w%d]%-.-%d%p%d%d\n)\n[\n]*"

 for w in string.gmatch(tempRec, paytternToMatch) do
       print(w)
 end
```

But when I am removing 0 from the last row in the below mentioed string. The pattern is not matching.  any help would be appreicated.

```
local tempRec = [[

ABC01-USD-0322-A Total DUE amount : 2312.08  USD
Value Date : 31 MAY       2011
   Details:ABCDE - BCD: / ABC01 0212 23.79 / ARM01 0311 870.79
   Details:FGHIJ - BCD: / ABC01 0323 1.88
   Details:KLMNO - BCD: / ABC01 0314 1,035.99
   Details:PQRST - BCD: / ABC01 0315 677.61
   Details:UVWXY - BCD: / ABC01 0316 362.75
   Details:ZABCD - BCD: / ABC01 0317   .28

   ]]
paytternToMatch = "(%w%w%w[%w%d][%w%d]%-.-%d%p%d%d\n)\n[\n]*"

 for w in string.gmatch(tempRec, paytternToMatch) do
       print(w)
 end
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to extract from that string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that the digit before the punctuation is not optional in your pattern.  Simply add a `*` to match as many digits, but allowing no digits as well.  The other option is to use a `?` if you only want to match a single or no digits, but not any additional digits before that.

```
paytternToMatch = "(%w%w%w[%w%d][%w%d]%-.-%d*%p%d%d\n)\n[\n]*"
--                                          ^ here
```

Note that there are several other improvements that you may want to consider in addition to this.  For example, this will ignore that digit entirely since the previous `.-` will include it, change the punctuation to only allow a `.`, and change the line feed requirement a bit:

```
paytternToMatch = "(%w%w%w[%w%d][%w%d]%-.-%.%d%d\n)\n+"
```

See [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html) for more detail on patterns.

Comment: @B Mitch, It seems your answer is working fine. I will do some more testing against your provided pattern. I must say Thank you for your wonderful support.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern requires a number before the decimal point:

```
paytternToMatch = "(%w%w%w[%w%d][%w%d]%-.-%d*%p%d%d\n)\n[\n]*"
```

additionally, you may want to more sensible captures:

```
paytternToMatch = "(%w%w%w[%w%d][%w%d])%-.-(%d*%p%d%d)\n[\n]+"
```

Comment: paytternToMatch = "(%w%w%w[%w%d][%w%d])%-.-(%d*%p%d%d)\n[\n]+" not working, it is only fetching "ABC01"